# How to print specified in java--->

Tags: java

I want to print the below pattern

```
 v   v
  v v
   v
```

Below is the code which I have tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 final int numRows = 4;
 for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) 
  {
     for (int preSpace = numRows - row; preSpace >= 0; preSpace--)
     {
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
     if (row > 0) 
       {
         System.out.print("v");
         for (int postSpace = 1; postSpace < row * 2; postSpace++)
          {
             System.out.print(" ");
           }
        }                   
   }
    System.out.println("v");
 }
```

I'm getting the below output:

```
  v
 v v
v   v
```

Can anyone help me to solve this pattern?

Comment: Your code does not appear to be working and I can't reproduce the output you gave.  If it _were_ working, you should simply be able to reverse the order of iteration of the loop and all would be fine.

Comment: I had already used the code @tim, and it was working properly. But didn't give my required output.

Comment: @amitmahajan Your answer was great...too bad you deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tim's answer was correct (Only that his print statement was outside the loop, but before i could edit or comment, it was deleted. So i am posting my own).

Basically you just have to reverse your outer most loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int numRows = 4;
    for (int row = numRows-1; row >= 0; row--) {
        for (int preSpace = numRows - row; preSpace >= 0; preSpace--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        if (row > 0) {
            System.out.print("v");
            for (int postSpace = 1; postSpace < row * 2; postSpace++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }                   
        System.out.println("v");
    }
}
```

Comment: This would appear to be your lucky day.  And yes, I've been striking out all day, minus +10 reputation points from a really old question.

Comment: just change final int numRows = 4; to final int numRows = 3; to get what @Chester want

Answer (score 0):

I would create a pattern so you can easily draw anything you need

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declare a 2D array and DRAW IT!
        char[][] pattern = 
            {{ 'v',' ',' ',' ','v'},
             { ' ','v',' ','v',' '},
             { ' ',' ','v',' ',' '}};

     for (int row = 0; row < pattern.length; row++) 
     {
         for (int col = 0; col < pattern[0].length; col ++)
         {
             System.out.print(pattern[row][col]);
         }
         System.out.println();  // \n at the end
     }
}
```

Output:

```
v   v
 v v 
  v
```

Answer (score 0):

Observing the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle, I'd cheat and do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("v   v");
  System.out.println(" v v");
  System.out.println("  v");
}
```

This might not be the spirit of the exercise, but keeping things simple is a very important lesson to learn in software development. Simple, clean code = ease of maintenance = less buggy.

Comment: lol. Seriously? I think he had a problem to solve. I'm sure he didn't want a Hello World program on the problem.

Comment: Not entirely serous no, but in my profession an a Java developer I have seen countless examples of code which is far more complicated that it needs to be, and have replaced 100-line long methods with 5-line long ones which do the same thing much more simply. So the advice about keeping things simple is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for you:

```
final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("");

for (int row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
    for (int preSpace = row - 1; preSpace > 0; preSpace--) {
        out.append(" ");
    }

    if (row < numRows) {
        out.append("v");
    }

    if (row == numRows) {
        out.append("v");
    } 
    else {
        for (int midSpace = 2 - (row-1)*2; midSpace >= 0; midSpace--) {
            out.append(" ");
        }
    }

    if (row < numRows) {
        out.append("v");
    }

    for (int postSpace = row - 1; postSpace > 0; postSpace--) {
        out.append(" ");
    }

    out.append(System.lineSeparator());
}

System.out.print(out.toString());
```